# Sending image to telegram chat in a single message, with formatted multiline text, using curl in bash

Tags: linux, bash, curl, telegram-bot

I'd like to send (in a **single** message) an image with some text, formatted and multiline.

I think there's a way to achieve my goal as I can see this type of posts in different telegram groups (single messages with an image and a lot of multiline formatted text)

I'm able to send multiline formatted text using sendMessage, ie:

`curl -X POST "https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXX/sendMessage" -d chat_id=YYYY -d text="<b>some bold text</b>%0Asome text in the second line%0Aand some in a third line" -d parse_mode="HTML"`

Trying with an image, using sendPhoto ... no fun, ie:

`curl -X POST "https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXX/sendPhoto" -F chat_id=YYYY -F photo=@"path_to_photo.jpg" -F caption='line one%0Aline two' -F parse_mode="HTML"`

I'll get my photo and the string `line one%0Aline two` as the caption
(sending only the image is ok)

My workaround at the moment is to split my post in 2 two different messages, using both sendPhoto and sendMessage.

Btw, I've used "-d" when using sendMessage and "-F" with sendPhoto, following examples found googling the issue.

I'm on an Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Thx for any working example :-X

Benno

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: You did not explain why you switched from using `-d` (`--data`) to using `-F` (`--form`). Please add this to your question.

Comment: Edited, thx Cyrus and Xhienne